# session values and compatibility?

Tags: cross-browser

I have compatibility issues with Internet Explorer 8 in running an application. And those compatibility issues also affect the session values in C#.

Is there any other way to make the session values unaffected by compatibility issues?

E. g.: I am storing a usersid in the session while logging in, and according to the session value it loads the privilege in a listbox.

THIS IS THE SCENARIO:

1. I am logging in to my application as admin; the privileges allocated for admin gets loaded. After that I'm logging out
2. I was trying logging in as different user it loads the users privileges in the listbox.
3. This is where the problem arises. When logging in as admin again, it loads the privileges of the user previously logged in and not the admin's privileges in the listbox. And on checking the session value it was having the previous user's user id.

Can anyone guide me in getting out of this?

The same issue seems to work well with IE6. But the problem arises with IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a browser problem - the session ID is kept in a browser cookie, and the session values on the server. Reading and writing of cookies is a basic browser function and has not changed between IE6 and IE8. I'd suggest looking at your code, not the browser.

Comment: yeah thank u !.i just changed the internet options to clear off the cookies every time i visit a webpage.it is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

i just changed the internet options to clear off the cookies every time i visit a webpage.it is working fine now